# Can I use Selenium for end to end tests on an existing Web Application?

Tags: testing, selenium

I am using Karma for unit tests and it works great.

The tests I would like to run would look similar to this:

```
1. var $input = $("#foo");
2. var $button = $("#bar");
3. $input.val("HELLO WARLD");
4. $button.trigger("click");
5. expect(window.appData.foo).toBe("HELLO WARLD");
```

[Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) looks like it might be the right choice but I don't know if there is a better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  You can use Selenium for end-to-end automated tests on existing web applications.

Selenium is designed to automate web browsers.  It's certainly a good choice for what you want.   I'm sure there are other options, but as Selenium is used by several big companies, including Google for their automated web testing technologies, you will be safe with Selenium assuming you implement it optimally.

The only thing to keep in mind, is that GUI testing is **NOT** supposed to replace unit tests.

[image: testing pyramid]

GUI testing should be your least used testing methodology.  You can, however, use Selenium to test your Acceptance tests which is what many companies do.